# Magento 2 error after upgrade and deploy

Tags: magento2

## For a template in magento 2 we had to do following in SSH

Run command line: php bin/magento module:enable MGS_Mpanel
Run command line: php bin/magento module:enable MGS_Mmegamenu
Run command line: php bin/magento module:enable MGS_Portfolio
Run command line: php bin/magento module:enable MGS_Testimonial
Run command line: php bin/magento module:enable MGS_Brand
Run command line: php bin/magento module:enable MGS_Core
Run command line: php bin/magento module:enable MGS_Promobanners
Run command line: php bin/magento module:enable MGS_StoreLocator
Run command line: php bin/magento module:enable MGS_Blog
Run command line: php bin/magento module:enable MGS_QuickView
Run command line: php bin/magento module:enable MGS_AdvancedReports
Run command line: php bin/magento setup:upgrade
Run command line: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

## Magento was installed correctly, but after deploy we get following error:

a:4:{i:0;s:294:"Warning: include(/home/[myusername]/domains/[mydomain]/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/[myusername]/domains/[mydomain]/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Io.php on line 158";i:1;s:2288:"#0 /home/[myusername]/domains/[mydomain]/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Io.php(158): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'include(/home/d...', '/home/[myusername]/...', 158, Array)
1 /home/[myusername]/domains/[mydomain]/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Io.php(158): include()

2 /home/[myusername]/domains/[mydomain]/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php(202): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Io->includeFile('/home/[myusername]/...')

3 /home/[myusername]/domains/[mydomain]/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php(92): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->shouldSkipGeneration('interceptor', 'Magento\Framewo...', 'Magento\Framewo...')

4 /home/[myusername]/domains/[mydomain]/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\Framewo...')

5 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Magento\Framewo...')

6 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Magento\Framewo...')

7 /home/[myusername]/domains/[mydomain]/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\Framewo...')

8 /home/[myusername]/domains/[mydomain]/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\Framewo...')

9 /home/[myusername]/domains/[mydomain]/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Magento\Framewo...')

10 /home/[myusername]/domains/[mydomain]/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewo...')

11 /home/[myusername]/domains/[mydomain]/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(114): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Framewo...')

12 /home/[myusername]/domains/[mydomain]/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()

13 /home/[myusername]/domains/[mydomain]/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))

14 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}

## Any ideas on how to solve this have no clue and tried re-installing this for a few times now.

Comment: The error in the front end:

Warning: include(/home/[username]/domains/[mydomain]/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/[username]/domains/[mydomain]/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Io.php on line 158

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.
Please remove var/di/* and var/generation/* using following command from your Magento project's root directory

```
rm -Rf var/di/* var/generation/*
```